# $wpdb working with ajax but showing ajax error instead of success

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax

Will someone guide why this code doesn't work. Even the data gets changed.
Here is the ajax I use.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".ue_ajax_enabled").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */
        $.ajax({
            url:  ue_ajax.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            /*dataType: 'json',*/
            data: {
                'action'    : 'ue_ajax_enabled',
                'new_username'  : $("#new_username").val(),
                'nonce'     : $("#new_username_nonce_check").val(),
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".ue_ajax_enabled").text(ue_ajax.beforeMessage);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Success');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error');
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
        
    });
});
```

Here is the ajax action hook I use.

```
    add_action( "wp_ajax_ue_ajax_enabled", 'ue_ajax_enabled' );
    
    function ue_ajax_enabled() {
    global $wpdb;

    $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $currentUser->ID;

    if (  is_user_logged_in() && wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], 'new_username_nonce' ) && ! empty($_REQUEST['new_username'])) {

        // Get name of our users table
        $tableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';

        if ( !username_exists( $_REQUEST['new_username'] ) ) {
            // Stripslashes and trim any whitespace, also replace whitespace with underscore
            $newUsername = trim(str_replace(' ', '_', stripslashes($_REQUEST['new_username'])));
        } else {
            echo json_encode( array('username' => 'Username exists, try any other') );
            die();
        }

        // Data to change
        $dataToChange = array('user_login' => $newUsername);

        // Where to Change
        $whereToChange = array('ID' => $user_id); 

        // Change the data inside the table
        $result = $wpdb->update($tableName, $dataToChange, $whereToChange, array('%s'), array('%d'));


        if ($result) {
            echo json_encode( array('update' => true) );
        } else {
            echo json_encode( array('update' => false) );
            die();
        }

        if (ue_send_email_to_user()) {
            $subject = 'Username Changed Successfully ID:' . $user_id;
            $message = "<p>You username has been successfully changed. Your new details are given below.</p>";
            $message .= "<strong>Previous Username:</strong><span>{$currentUser->user_login}</span>";
            $message .= "<strong>New Username</strong><span>{$newUsername}</span>";
            $from = "From: " . get_bloginfo('name');

            wp_mail( array(ue_get_administrators_email(), $currentUser->email), $subject, $message, $from );
        }
    }
    die();
}
```

The code throws an error message in the console instead of the success message of the ajax set earlier. Any clue why this happens.
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE: by commenting datatype the problem solves. But still it shows undefined when i access json.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code is simple: if you want to send a JSON response, then make sure it's a valid JSON response, i.e. send the correct `Content-Type` header and a proper JSON-encoded body. With `jQuery.ajax()`, though, you can omit the header, but you'd need to set the `dataType` to `json`.

```php
function my_ajax_callback1() {
    // Invalid JSON response.
    die();
}

function my_ajax_callback2() {
    // Good JSON response with a Content-Type header.

    header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
    echo json_encode( array( 'update' => true ) );

    wp_die(); // die() works, but wp_die() is better
}
```

And actually, in your callback, you could simply use [`wp_send_json()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/) like so:

```php
function my_ajax_callback3() {
    wp_send_json( array( 'update' => true ) );
    // No need to call wp_die(), die() or exit().
}
```

And there also [`wp_send_json_success()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/) and [`wp_send_json_error()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/), but in your JS, you would need to use `data.data.<key>` and not `data.<key>`, except for `data.success`.

```php
function my_ajax_callback4() {
    // ... your code

    // In your success( data ) JS, you'd access the 'update' value via data.data.update

    if ( $result ) {
        wp_send_json_success( array( 'update' => true, 'msg' => 'Success!' ) );
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error( array( 'update' => false, 'msg' => 'Foo error' ) );
    }
}
```

So be sure to return a valid response data and although not required, I suggest you to consider [creating a custom REST API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) for your custom AJAX action and point your AJAX requests to that API endpoint — which (by default) always returns a JSON response.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I mentioned that I solved the error. But your code is far better than my code. This is a nice answer. Thanks for teaching.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot an action of ajax in WP when submitting you not login. So, if you want it to fire on the front-end for both visitors and logged-in users, you can do this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
```

and after return ajax, you must use `die()` function to respond to the return data.

Read more: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: I use it only for logged in users.

Comment: In the die(); function, I don't see you return the message data after the success or fail process.

Comment: we don't need to send message in die() because i am already using json_encode().

Comment: The question solved by commenting datatype

Comment: thanks for your help too. Keep supporting others